# How to take the output from web form and POST it to an XML API?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, web

I am trying to take information given in a web form (HTML, JS or other) and use this information to populate an XML document that is then submitted to an API all on the client side.

As simple as I thought this sounds, I am stuck I have been through the best option I have so far is for JS to populate an XML document using variables but I am not sure how to submit the document. This is slightly unusual as it is all hosted locally so could make use of other things if that would work, then need to present the returned XML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: What type of framework are you using? (ASP.NET, PHP, etc)

Comment: How would you like to submit the XML document to the server? As a traditional POST request (the user clicks a Submit button to submit the form and reload the page), or as an AJAX call?

Comment: As a traditional POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this great reference for working with XML in JavaScript:

[AJAX and XML handling in JavaScript](http://help.dottoro.com/ljarvfic.php)

You can create an [XMLDocument](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbcjfot.php) object, and then [serialize](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwwrcvr.php) it to a string so it can be submitted to the API.

**Edit 1**

To serialize an XMLDocument in IE8 and earlier, use the [.xml property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhwhicc.php).

**Edit 2**

Once you have your serialized XML document as a string, you can place it into a `<form>` so it can be submitted to the server.  Here's one way of doing it:

HTML

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="xmldata" id="hiddenXMLInput">
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit XML to server">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('hiddenXMLInput').value = strXMLDocument;
```

where `strXMLDocument` is your serialized XML document as a string.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this, when I run it in either chrome or Safari I get the following error - Your browser doesn't support the XMLDocument property. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've made [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2tTK/) to show how to create a new XMLDocument, add some elements to it, and serialize it to a string. It works in Safari and Chrome (but not in IE).